# Find the first derivative of the following function

Tags: calculus

> How do I get the first derivative of the following function:
>   $f(x)= \frac{1}{1+e^{3x}}$?

Also are the asymptotes I found correct?
MY ATTEMPT:

Vertical asymptotes:

$1+e^{3x}=0$

$3x\ln e=-1$

$x=-1/3$

Horizontal asymptotes:
No horizontal asymptotes

Slant asymptotes: 
None

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the question. It's hard to tell what `3xIne=-1 X=-1/3` is supposed to mean.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, I will.

Comment: @Happy, make sure you get your exponents right ...

Comment: $e^3x$ is not $e^{3x}$

Comment: If you want the second option, get in the habit of putting whatever u are exponenting in curly braces { }

Comment: dollar sign, e^{3x} dollar sign

Comment: Ok I sure will, thanks!

Comment: Also your VA is incorrect (see my edited post)

Comment: Thank you so much , I need more practice.

Comment: Wasn't a big error, just make sure you take ln of BOTH sides :)

Comment: And your welcome

Comment: @Happy Handle the exponent as a product $3x$ clubbed together upstairs. There is a horizontal asymptote as x-axis, y=0  which it tends to. No vertical asymptotes.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{1+e^{3x}}$$
$$f(x)= (1+e^{3x})^{-1}$$ (just rewrote it)
$$f'(x)= -1(1+e^{3x})^{-2}(e^{3x})(3)$$
$$f'(x)= -\frac{3e^{3x}}{(1+e^{3x})^2}$$
Simple chain rule

---

Also for VA:

$$ 1 + e^{3x} = 0$$
$$ e^{3x} = -1$$
$$ ln(e^{3x}) = ln(-1)$$
$$ 3x = ln(-1)$$
$$ 3x = undefined$$

You cannot take ln(negative number). Thus the VA does not exist.

Comment: Understand? First I rewrote it to make it simpler, then it was a chain rule problem, that is your first deriative

Comment: yes I understand.

Comment: Very clearly written. I wonder how come the OP hasn't yet upvoted. +1